# Ordering values within each factor in R

Tags: r

I have been having this problem for a while and have been using time consuming methods to do this. I know there must be a better way to do this. Suppose I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)
group <- c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3))
score <- runif(9)
score.2 <- rnorm(9)
df <- data.frame(group,score,score.2)

df

  group     score    score.2
1     a 0.2875775 -0.1089660
2     a 0.7883051 -0.1172420
3     a 0.4089769  0.1830826
4     b 0.8830174  1.2805549
5     b 0.9404673 -1.7272706
6     b 0.0455565  1.6901844
7     c 0.5281055  0.5038124
8     c 0.8924190  2.5283366
9     c 0.5514350  0.5490967
```

What I want is similar data but with just the top two values for `score` for each factor or character column (might be different if group is factor class or character class?), but I also want `score.2` to remain in the data. So the final output should only have 6 rows of data. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why are you using `as.data.frame(cbind(.))`? Do you *want* "score" to be a character or factor?

Comment: @theamateurdatanalyst You could have done `data.frame(group,score)` and still group would be factor.

Comment: You only fixed the "group" column. You can just do `data.frame(group, score)`.

Comment: Whoa, thanks guys. I didn't know this. Will def make my life easier from now on.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst I updated the post, though not sure if that is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `slice` from `dplyr 0.3` devel version

```
 library(dplyr)
 df%>%
     group_by(group)%>%
     arrange(desc(score))%>%
     slice(1:2) #or 
    # do(head(., 2)) # in `dplyr 0.2` 
 #   Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
 #Groups: group

 # group     score    score.2
 #1     a 0.7883051 -0.1172420
 #2     a 0.4089769  0.1830826
 #3     b 0.9404673 -1.7272706
 #4     b 0.8830174  1.2805549
 #5     c 0.8924190  2.5283366
 #6     c 0.5514350  0.5490967
```

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[order(group, -score), head(.SD,2), by=group]
 #     group     score    score.2
 #1:     a 0.7883051 -0.1172420
 #2:     a 0.4089769  0.1830826
 #3:     b 0.9404673 -1.7272706
 #4:     b 0.8830174  1.2805549
 #5:     c 0.8924190  2.5283366
 #6:     c 0.5514350  0.5490967
```

Comment: What if there are other columns? Will this still work?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst Do you need the other columns or just needs the selected column alone?  The `slice` is selecting the rows by position.

Comment: yes, perfect give me just a sec to test it on a more complex set.

Comment: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "slice"` Any idea why? I did `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: @theamteurdataanalyst I guess you are using dplyr 0.2   In that case, instead of the slice you could use `do(head(.,2))`

Answer (score 3):

here is a base solution if anyone uses base r anymore

```
set.seed(123)
group <- c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3))
score <- runif(9)
score.2 <- rnorm(9)
df <- data.frame(group,score,score.2)

do.call(rbind, 
        by(df, df$group, function(x) 
          x[head(order(x$score, decreasing = TRUE), 2), ]))

#     group     score    score.2
# a.2     a 0.7883051 -0.1172420
# a.3     a 0.4089769  0.1830826
# b.5     b 0.9404673 -1.7272706
# b.4     b 0.8830174  1.2805549
# c.8     c 0.8924190  2.5283366
# c.9     c 0.5514350  0.5490967
```